# Struggling to create dataframe, ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 12 fields in line 15, saw 16

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a dataframe reading in a text file. I have executed the following:

`result = pd.read_csv("EconData.txt", sep="\s+", header=None)`

But I keep receiving:

> 'Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 12 fields in line 15, saw 16'

I understand that this may be because some rows may contain extra columns with no actual column being made for these values. However, I need all the columns from 5 onward to be merged as this is part of one long string which seems to be separated due the delimiter I am using.

Below is an example of how my text file is laid out. If I wanted to split between the Date, Time, Initials and Message what would be the best way to approach this.

```
16/10/2018, 20:00 - MP: The walkie talkie app

16/10/2018, 20:00 - MP: Dobby remembers
```

Comment: Your sentences are of different length, so you can't and shouldn't parse by `\s+`. Instead, parse by `sep=',|-|:`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since the message part may contain various commas and colons would this cause more columns to be created? Also can I separate by more than once character.

result = pd.read_csv("EconData.txt", sep=",|-|:", header=None) 

Is this how it would be?

Comment: Commas and colons are ignored once you specified `sep='\s+'`.

Comment: Considering I use your approach, sep=',|:|-' would this cause more columns to be created if I had commas and colons in the message column? If so can I avoid this?

Comment: Yes, you can separate by multiple characters, but may need to pass `engine='python'` in some version.

Comment: I have tried, it now comes up with the message:

Expected 6 fields in line 688, saw 7. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.

Comment: Error is most likely because message contains one of the separation characters. Take a look at line 688 to see if that's true.

Comment: Yes it does, there are many other lines after this which also contains some separation characters.

Comment: You should probably read and parse the file manually.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I first misunderstood your question. I thought you were parsing a text.

If you want to import a csv with a text field at the end of each row that may contain separators, but is not correctly quoted, you could work as follows:

1. load the file into one text column
2. split the number of wanted columns off, ignoring the separators in the last column

You can do that as follows:

```
df= pd.read_csv(your_file_name, sep='\n', names=['text'])
# now split the first 5 columns
df_split= df['text'].str.split('\s+', n=5, expand=True)
```

If your dataframe contains column names, you can recover them like this

```
df_split.columns= df_split.iloc[0].to_list()
df_split.drop(df.index[0], inplace=True)
```

The only disadvantage is, that your columns will all be of type object this way. So you either need to convert the columns to the desired type yourself, or if you want to use pandas' automatic type detection, you can also just write the file back to a file (or an instance of io.StringIO if it is not large) and reread it from pandas. Pandas will take care of the separators by adding quotes automatically, so when you reread it, you will not face the same problem again.

Test:

```
raw="""col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
a b c d
A B C D E F G H I J"""
df= pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(raw), sep='\n', names=['text'])
# now split the first 5 columns
df_split= df['text'].str.split('\s+', n=5, expand=True)
df_split.columns= df_split.iloc[0].to_list()
df_split.drop(df.index[0], inplace=True)

Out[373]: 
  col1 col2 col3 col4  col5       col6
1    1    2    3    4     5    6 7 8 9
2    a    b    c    d  None       None
3    A    B    C    D     E  F G H I J
```

Comment: So it is a .txt file I'm using, the format of the text is as above. However, as some messages are really long they seem to end up on the next line causing some inaccurate fields. I guess I would need to somehow clean the data up somehow.

Comment: Oh in that case yes. Doesn't sound like an easy job! Maybe you can work with a regex to decide whether it is indeed a new line or just the rest of the previous line. If a proper line starts with a date, you can probably reduce the "false positives" to a minimum.